# Group price with start and end date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table

```
Recordid Price  Start date    end date 
-----------------------------------------
1        20     2017-10-01    2017-10-02
2        20     2017-10-03    2017-10-04
3        30     2017-10-05    2017-10-05
4        20     2017-10-06    2017-10-07
```

I want to get every price when it started and when it ended so my result set would be

```
20.  2017-10-01.  2017-10-04
30.  2017-10-05.  2017-10-05
20.  2017-10-06.  2017-10-07
```

I'm having problems to figure it out

It's an Oracle database

Comment: I don't understand the rules.  how do you determine the two output records for price 20?

Comment: Simple first the price was 20 from the first till the fourth as the first two record say then it was one day 30 as int the third record then two days 20 again as in the fourth record

Comment: Basically i need a way to group the first two records separate from the fourth but I'm having trouble figuring it out

Comment: What does each record in the original table represent? It isn't a price change because then records 1 and 2 would be represented by a single record that looks like this 

`1      |      20     |    2017-10-01    |    2017-10-04`

Comment: It has more data columns and Everytime there is a change in any column it splits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out with the code below

```
SELECT distinct price
      , case when start_dt is null then lag(start_dt) over (order by start_date) 
             else start_dt end realstart
      , case when end_dt is null then lead(end_dt) over (order by end_date) 
             else  end_dt end realend   
FROM (SELECT case when nvl(lag(price) over (order by start_date),-1) <> price then start_date end start_dt
           , case when nvl(lead(price) over (order by end_date),-1) <>price then end_date end end_dt
           , price 
           , start_date
           , end_date 
       FROM t) main 
WHERE start_dt is not null 
   or end_dt is not null
```

Comment: use the {} icon to put in a code block in the WYSIWYG editor or ctrl-K I believe.

Comment: Thanks! I Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that might work in your case:

```
select price, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_price = price and prev_end_date = start_date - 1
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (order by t.start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(t.end_date) over (order by t.start_date) as prev_end_date,
                   lag(t.price) over (order by t.start_date) as prev_price
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by price, grp
```

Comment: I don't see that this should solve it at all 
You assign 1 to the the first record 0 to the second so when you group it by that you get all four records

Comment: @JacobGoldhirsch . . . There is a cumulative sum that you are not taking into account.

Comment: OK I'll test it tomorrow

Comment: i tested it and as i said yesterday it does not solve anything

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data I think you want to have start date and end date whenever the price has been changed in order of the record id.
The following query may contain more sub queries than neccessary, because readability. The very inner select determines when the price has been changed here called group changes. The Next level froms the group by a rolling sum. This is possible, because the only the group change contains values > 0. The rest is obvious.

```
SELECT GRP, 
       PRICE, 
       MIN("Start date") AS "Start date", 
       MAX("end date") AS "end date"
  FROM ( SELECT sub.*,
                SUM(GROUP_CHANGE) OVER (ORDER BY RECORDID) AS GRP
           FROM ( SELECT t.*,
                         CASE 
                            WHEN RECORDID = LAG(t.RECORDID) OVER (ORDER BY t.PRICE, t.RECORDID) + 1 
                               THEN 0 
                            ELSE RECORDID 
                         END AS GROUP_CHANGE
                    FROM t ) sub ) fin
 GROUP BY GRP, PRICE 
 ORDER BY GRP


       GRP      PRICE Start date end date
---------- ---------- ---------- --------
         1         20 01.10.17   04.10.17 
         4         30 05.10.17   05.10.17 
         8         20 06.10.17   11.10.17
```

Tested with following data (Note that I have add some record to your deliverd sample data as I wanted to have a group with three records)

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   Recordid     INT,
   Price        INT, 
   "Start date" DATE,
   "end date"   DATE 
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,        20,     TO_DATE('2017-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),    TO_DATE('2017-10-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,        20,     TO_DATE('2017-10-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),    TO_DATE('2017-10-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3,        30,     TO_DATE('2017-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),    TO_DATE('2017-10-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4,        20,     TO_DATE('2017-10-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),    TO_DATE('2017-10-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5,        20,     TO_DATE('2017-10-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),    TO_DATE('2017-10-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6,        20,     TO_DATE('2017-10-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),    TO_DATE('2017-10-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```